# Rename EFI boot entry

Tags: grub, uefi

I did some tests with `efibootmgr` to rename the default Ubuntu boot entry.

I can create a new entry that boots my Ubuntu with:

```
sudo efibootmgr --create --disk /dev/sda --part 1 --label "Precise - GRUB2" --loader \\EFI\\ubuntu\\grubx64.efi
```

It seems it's not possible to use two entries with the `shimx64.efi`. The second has to use `grubx64.efi` instead.

But I can't delete the default entry with:

```
sudo efibootmgr -B -b 0001
```

The entry is deleted when I check it with `efibootmgr --verbose`. 
But, after reboot, the entry is listed in the BIOS,
and after Ubuntu reboot, the entry is still there.

I only want to rename the default entry, but it seems that's not possible. 
I have to delete it and create a new one.  But deleting doesn't work either.

Comment: Before I did same, but found that the new entry used /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg as configfile for loading full grub in my install. I wanted two different Ubuntu entries, but could not do it. Grub was since been updated & now there is a grub.cfg in my second UEFI entry in the ESP, but Ubuntu still uses grub in ubuntu original entry. Something is hard coded. Old bug, not sure if newer bug somewhere. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1625200

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your grub, so the entry will be permanent :

RHEL/Centos : `grub2-mkconfig -o  <path_to_your_grub_conf_file>`

Ubuntu : `update-grub`